# Downloading template from github

Tags: git, github, gentelella

I am trying to download the regular files only (html, css, js, etc..) for this template: [gentelella admin panel](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella), but when I download the .zip and unzip it, I get to see not a 'ready to upload to ftp' template but rather a template mixed up with some package.json, bower.json and it is not clear to me how to get the regular template.. Sorry if this seems stupid to you for me to ask, but I really don't understand how to get only the files I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is the source code and the files needed to compile it into the CSS, JS etc.

What you're probably after is the contents of the `build` folder. It looks like this contains the JS & CSS files that are ready to use.

Comment: but int his folder I can not find the html's.. any idea how to compile everything?

Comment: It may be the production folder you're actually after, as this seems to include HTML samples. The documentation folder looks like it's worth checking out - it's got HTML files that contain HTML samples for different elements.